# Localize messages for user accross the solution

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, resources, localization

I have one solution with many projects. Each of the projects at some point throws errors, or returns some messages for the user to see.

How can I localize these messages?

At first the solution seemed obvious - to put messages in resx files in a separate project (so everyone could reference it) but it seems I cannot access another assemblies resources. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but it seems I cannot access another assemblies resources. Is there a workaround?

You could use `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator` as a Custom Tool generator for your resource files which would make public classes accessible from everywhere:

[image]

or you could also do this using the Wizard:

[image]